# The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

I've created a view in SQL Server that contains the most important columns from different tables.
Printing the content of the table to the ASP.NET MVC view works fine, but when I want to get the details of a single record  the problem occur.

> The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.

I navigate to the specific record doing this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {  id=item.Record_number  })
```

Record number is the primary key. I set this manually by right clicking on the specific variable in the `.edmx` model. Then I try to get the specific data using the following:

```
    //
    // GET: /Record/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            RecordDataView record = db.RecordDataView.Find(id); //HERE THE ERROR OCCUR
            if (record == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(record);
        }
        catch(EntityException)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("NoDatabaseConnection", "Home");
        }
    }
```

And the model look like this:

```
namespace Implant.Database
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class RecordDataView
    {
        public int Record_number { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Record_date { get; set; }

        /** rest of code omitted */ 
    }
}
```

At the moment I am using the following code to make it all work. But I don't feel this is a very good way or efficient. And I am very curious how to fix the failure above!

```
    //
    // GET: /Record/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        var record = from r in db.RecordDataView
                     select r;
        if (id != 0)
        {
            record = record.Where(r => r.Record_number == id);
        }
        RecordDataView rec = record.ToList().First(); 

        return View(rec);   
    }
```

Someone got any idea why this error occurs? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you set your Primary Key in `.edmx` you should update your database too, because you have PK in your model and not in your database.  **Update: does not work for views.**

For views use `.SingleOrDefault` instead of `Find()`.

In this scenario change the following line: `RecordDataView record = db.RecordDataView.Find(id);` 
To the following: `RecordDataView recorddataview = db.RecordDataView.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Record_number == id);`

Comment: Is it possible to add a primary key to a view in the database?

Comment: Sorry I thought that you said that you added PK to normal table in edmx file not to view. Did you try .SingleOrDefault instead Find() ?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much! I then changed the following line:

`RecordDataView record = db.RecordDataView.Find(id); //HERE THE ERROR OCCUR`

To the following: 

`RecordDataView recorddataview = db.RecordDataView.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Record_number == id);`

Again, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your database table doesn't specify a primary key field, your edmx model will assume each field is a key. So ensure your database and your entity model as saying the same thing.

If your model and database correctly specify the primary key, then, you can use .Find() and it will work.